# converting named-vector (from TukeyHSD) to a table

Tags: r

I have a named vector which is part of the output of TukeyHSD:

```
"a-b" "a-c" "b-c"
  1     2     3
```

is there a nice way to convert it to

```
    a  b  c
  -----------
a |    1  2
b | 1     3
c | 2  3
```

? or do I just hack at it and split strings and so forth

thanks in advance

here is the dput output:

`c(`b-a`= 0.132736594352255,`c-a`= 0.999921265128142,` 
d-a`= 0.801948385014406,`e-a`= 1,`f-a`= 0.999999993422497,` 
g-a`= 0.999994493135286,`h-a`= 0.210958663031597,` 
i-a`= 1.8980767408916e-06,`j-a`= 0.973055228316854,` 
k-a`= 0.999999989980955,`m-a`= 0.999999999847843,` 
n-a`= 0.00176609502582648,`p-a`= 0.738916850855589,` 
c-b`= 0.0648789689498736,`d-b`= 0.00274896267890112,` 
e-b`= 0.217149424299426,`f-b`= 0.0563761493313133,` 
g-b`= 0.830288996389741,`h-b`= 1.37129030743921e-05,` 
i-b`= 0.292237803866045,`j-b`= 0.00203363512911592,` 
k-b`= 0.429789314314218,`m-b`= 0.893873188901534,` 
n-b`= 1.26129400479513e-07,`p-b`= 0.0148404046180679,` 
d-c`= 0.999413140979136,`e-c`= 0.999983194608954,` 
f-c`= 0.999999593776059,`g-c`= 0.99450256286738,` 
h-c`= 0.995948206958786,`i-c`= 2.12711732894277e-06,` 
j-c`= 0.999999999953707,`k-c`= 0.99849672006282,` 
m-c`= 0.999945483624277,`n-c`= 0.159133209452148,` 
p-c`= 0.981199963747256,`e-d`= 0.894189247372541,` 
f-d`= 0.927465343408835,`g-d`= 0.679255997014174,` 
h-d`= 1,`i-d`= 2.48392421076105e-08,`j-d`= 0.999592315002344,` 
k-d`= 0.697136248874886,`m-d`= 0.958196387101045,` 
n-d`= 0.823800464142429,`p-d`= 0.999990479586194,` 
f-e`= 0.999999999789834,`g-e`= 0.999995787557262,` 
h-e`= 0.53201292841468,`i-e`= 1.03081411517714e-05,` 
j-e`= 0.995077423573089,`k-e`= 0.999999990349601,` 
m-e`= 0.999999999728218,`n-e`= 0.00827803916192571,` 
p-e`= 0.801239862126994,`g-f`= 0.999679361401266,` 
h-f`= 0.464857165472924,`i-f`= 4.11179760018143e-07,` 
j-f`= 0.998610646241627,`k-f`= 0.999980920365226,` 
m-f`= 0.999999813932987,`n-f`= 0.00531987647573118,` 
p-f`= 0.848849590006324,`h-g`= 0.341590849630092,` 
i-g`= 0.00156077688059131,`j-g`= 0.914056068033521,` 
k-g`= 0.999999999582086,`m-g`= 0.999999999998442,` 
n-g`= 0.00550711110598001,`p-g`= 0.589694361848451,` 
i-h`= 1.32359012638972e-10,`j-h`= 0.981457563281897,` 
k-h`= 0.217452285021171,`m-h`= 0.909323296631876,`n-h`= 
    0.329509866222374,` 
p-h`= 0.999896413565643,`j-i`= 2.4844853951933e-09,` 
k-i`= 4.94704403456447e-05,`m-i`= 0.0101526672020547,` 
n-i`= 1.28862254200612e-10,`p-i`= 3.63259988322984e-06,` 
k-j`= 0.923957489008565,`m-j`= 0.998615227094082,` 
n-j`= 0.0479071931248186,`p-j`= 0.983802108362677,` 
m-k`= 1,`n-k`= 0.00201102356142246,`p-k`= 0.638580957139582,` 
n-m`= 0.121254171582127,`p-m`= 0.857057426831322,` 
p-n` = 0.999990553111872)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you `dput(your vector)` so we can try and help?

Comment: thanks @RAB - I've added the dput output to the question. Each pair is actually \`a-b\` (with the backticks)
@Teekea - I haven't started yet - I was wondering if there is an idiomatic way to do this... It must be a common request to produce tables from Tukey, and I couldn't see how to do it (Google search) - very happy to start just hacking though :)

Comment: @user2162871 Your sample data is not valid R code! As suggested by RAB please provide the `dput` of your vector.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks - that is exactly the output from dput. Each pair is actually surrounded with \` (so \`a-b\`), but they have disappeared in the formatting. I will try to fix that.

Comment: @user2162871 Ah yes, I realised (too late) that that's what must've happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
library(tidyverse)
stack(x) %>%
    separate(ind, c("x", "y"), sep = "-") %>%
    mutate(
        x = factor(x, levels = sort(union(x, y))),
        y = factor(y, levels = sort(union(x, y)))) %>%
    complete(x, y) %>%
    spread(y, values)
## A tibble: 14 x 15
#   x            a        b        c        d        e        f        g
#   <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 a     NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2 b      1.33e-1 NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 3 c     10.00e-1  6.49e-2 NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 4 d      8.02e-1  2.75e-3  9.99e-1 NA       NA       NA       NA
# 5 e      1.00e+0  2.17e-1 10.00e-1  8.94e-1 NA       NA       NA
# 6 f     10.00e-1  5.64e-2 10.00e-1  9.27e-1 10.00e-1 NA       NA
# 7 g     10.00e-1  8.30e-1  9.95e-1  6.79e-1 10.00e-1 10.00e-1 NA
# 8 h      2.11e-1  1.37e-5  9.96e-1  1.00e+0  5.32e-1  4.65e-1  0.342
# 9 i      1.90e-6  2.92e-1  2.13e-6  2.48e-8  1.03e-5  4.11e-7  0.00156
#10 j      9.73e-1  2.03e-3 10.00e-1 10.00e-1  9.95e-1  9.99e-1  0.914
#11 k     10.00e-1  4.30e-1  9.98e-1  6.97e-1 10.00e-1 10.00e-1  1.000
#12 m     10.00e-1  8.94e-1 10.00e-1  9.58e-1 10.00e-1 10.00e-1  1.000
#13 n      1.77e-3  1.26e-7  1.59e-1  8.24e-1  8.28e-3  5.32e-3  0.00551
#14 p      7.39e-1  1.48e-2  9.81e-1 10.00e-1  8.01e-1  8.49e-1  0.590
## ... with 7 more variables: h <dbl>, i <dbl>, j <dbl>, k <dbl>, m <dbl>,
##   n <dbl>, p <dbl>
```

Note that this fills only the lower triangular part of the matrix. It's straightforward to copy values over to the upper triangular part.

---

### Sample data

```
x <- c("b-a" =  0.132736594352255,"c-a" =  0.999921265128142,
"d-a" =  0.801948385014406,"e-a" =  1,"f-a" =  0.999999993422497,
"g-a" =  0.999994493135286,"h-a" =  0.210958663031597,
"i-a" =  1.8980767408916e-06,"j-a" =  0.973055228316854,
"k-a" =  0.999999989980955,"m-a" =  0.999999999847843,
"n-a" =  0.00176609502582648,"p-a" =  0.738916850855589,
"c-b" =  0.0648789689498736,"d-b" =  0.00274896267890112,
"e-b" =  0.217149424299426,"f-b" =  0.0563761493313133,
"g-b" =  0.830288996389741,"h-b" =  1.37129030743921e-05,
"i-b" =  0.292237803866045,"j-b" =  0.00203363512911592,
"k-b" =  0.429789314314218,"m-b" =  0.893873188901534,
"n-b" =  1.26129400479513e-07,"p-b" =  0.0148404046180679,
"d-c" =  0.999413140979136,"e-c" =  0.999983194608954,
"f-c" =  0.999999593776059,"g-c" =  0.99450256286738,
"h-c" =  0.995948206958786,"i-c" =  2.12711732894277e-06,
"j-c" =  0.999999999953707,"k-c" =  0.99849672006282,
"m-c" =  0.999945483624277,"n-c" =  0.159133209452148,
"p-c" =  0.981199963747256,"e-d" =  0.894189247372541,
"f-d" =  0.927465343408835,"g-d" =  0.679255997014174,
"h-d" =  1,"i-d" =  2.48392421076105e-08,"j-d" =  0.999592315002344,
"k-d" =  0.697136248874886,"m-d" =  0.958196387101045,
"n-d" =  0.823800464142429,"p-d" =  0.999990479586194,
"f-e" =  0.999999999789834,"g-e" =  0.999995787557262,
"h-e" =  0.53201292841468,"i-e" =  1.03081411517714e-05,
"j-e" =  0.995077423573089,"k-e" =  0.999999990349601,
"m-e" =  0.999999999728218,"n-e" =  0.00827803916192571,
"p-e" =  0.801239862126994,"g-f" =  0.999679361401266,
"h-f" =  0.464857165472924,"i-f" =  4.11179760018143e-07,
"j-f" =  0.998610646241627,"k-f" =  0.999980920365226,
"m-f" =  0.999999813932987,"n-f" =  0.00531987647573118,
"p-f" =  0.848849590006324,"h-g" =  0.341590849630092,
"i-g" =  0.00156077688059131,"j-g" =  0.914056068033521,
"k-g" =  0.999999999582086,"m-g" =  0.999999999998442,
"n-g" =  0.00550711110598001,"p-g" =  0.589694361848451,
"i-h" =  1.32359012638972e-10,"j-h" =  0.981457563281897,
"k-h" =  0.217452285021171,"m-h" =  0.909323296631876,"n-h" =  0.329509866222374,
"p-h" =  0.999896413565643,"j-i" =  2.4844853951933e-09,
"k-i" =  4.94704403456447e-05,"m-i" =  0.0101526672020547,
"n-i" =  1.28862254200612e-10,"p-i" =  3.63259988322984e-06,
"k-j" =  0.923957489008565,"m-j" =  0.998615227094082,
"n-j" =  0.0479071931248186,"p-j" =  0.983802108362677,
"m-k" =  1,"n-k" =  0.00201102356142246,"p-k" =  0.638580957139582,
"n-m" =  0.121254171582127,"p-m" =  0.857057426831322,
"p-n" =  0.999990553111872)
```

Comment: that is just superb - thanks so much. tidyverse is really lovely. And yes, filling lower diagonal is just fine.

Comment: You're very welcome @user2162871, glad it was helpful